# Call Batch Apex From Javascript On-Click button

Tags: apex, javascript, batch

I have a single batch class, which calls a number of other batch classes when it runs. I'd like to be able to run this batch by pressing a custom javascript button. I've written a button to accomplish this (Based off an example), but it fails with the error:

> not ars found...

Here's the Batch code:

```
global class OCTAutomationProcessBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    string query = 'SELECT Name, Source_Table__c , Destination_Table__c , Source_Query__c, Criteria_Field_Key__c from OCT_Batch_Information__mdt' +
                    'Where Want_To_Process__c = True';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<OCT_Batch_Information__mdt> scope) {
    for(OCT_Batch_Information__mdt octBatchInfo : scope){
        OCTAutomationProcessBatchHandler.performLogic(octBatchInfo);
    }
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
}
```

Javascript code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 

var apexBatch= sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM ApexClass WHERE Name ='OCTAutomationProcessBatch'"); 

recordsclassid= apexBatch.getArray("records"); 

var checkBatchRunningRecords= sforce.connection.query("SELECT ApexClassId, status FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE ApexClassId ='"+recordsclassid[0].Id+"' AND Status NOT IN ('Completed','Aborted','Failed')"); 

records= checkBatchRunningRecords.getArray("records"); 

if(records.length>0){ 
window.alert("The batch job is currently executing. Please wait."); 
} 
else{ 
window.alert('The batch job has started.'); 
var batchid=sforce.apex.execute("OCTAutomationProcessBatch",{}); 

}
```

Comment: Can you post the error message verbatim?

Comment: args not specified

Answer (score 1):

maybe change:

```
var batchid=sforce.apex.execute
```

to

```
var batchid=sforce.apex.executeAnonymous
```

The first one needs the apex class to be a web service.